# MySQL multiple table query into one result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables like following

images_table

```
id   |  image_name   |   image_file
-----+---------------+------------------
1    |  flower       |  rose.jpg
2    |  fish         |  gold_fish.jpg
-----+---------------+----------------
```

tags_table

```
tag_id   |   tag_name   |  image_id
---------+--------------+---------------
1        |    rose      |   1
2        |  red flower  |   1
3        |  redfish     |   2
4        |  aquarium    |   2
---------+--------------+------------------
```

When someone search, I am using the following query

```
SELECT * FROM images_table WHERE image_name LIKE "%$search"
```

But I need to show results from both tables. ie combination of following queries

```
SELECT * FROM images_table WHERE image_name LIKE "%$search"

SELECT * FROM tags_table as tags LEFT JOIN images_table as img ON img.id=tags.image_id WHERE tags.tag_name LIKE "%$search"
```

How can I get both results as a single array/list? So that I can implement pagination as well.

Comment: Maybe you can use `JOIN` ?

Comment: question updated with a correct query, can you please check?

Comment: ok, you have join, how about `WHERe tags.tag_name LIKE "%$search" OR img.image_name LIKE "%$search";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT *

FROM images_table m1,
     tags_table m2

WHERE m1.image_table LIKE '%$search' OR m2.tag_name LIKE '%$search'
```

you just add both of the tables in the FROM part and give them alias thereafter in the where condition you add both of them you can use OR and also AND but that depends, OR will evaluate true if there is 1 match and AND will only will evaluate true if there are matches in both of the tables

Comment: comma separated join is not a good one, you should use join explicitly

Comment: agree to disagree, if the query is simple enough , there is nothing wrong with using comma separated join. When the query is more complex then i agree join explicitly must be used

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`

```
SELECT image_name, image_file, tag_name FROM images_table i
inner join tags_table t on i.id=t.image_id
WHERE image_name LIKE "%$search" and tag_name LIKE "%$search"
```